# SwiftUI how to get the current value during animation

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, swiftui, progress-bar

I want to create a circular progress bar using SwiftUI.

It has a red circle as the progress bar and text in the center as the current value.

Current code:

```
struct LoadingScreen: View {
@ObservedObject var manager : OnboardingManager;
    
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Circle()
            .stroke(lineWidth: 20.0)
            .opacity(0.3)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
        
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(min(self.manager.progress, 1.0)))
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
            .animation(.linear(duration: manager.progressDuration))
        
        Text(String(format: "%.0f %%", min(self.manager.progress, 1.0)*100.0))
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .bold().onTapGesture(perform: {
                manager.executeLoad()
            })
    }
}
```

}

When progress change from 0 -> 1.0 the red circle and text will run animation for 2 seconds. The animation of the circle worked fine but I don't know how to animate text from 0% -> 100% along with the circle. Please help